# How to pass <slots> content (provided by router-view) data back to component where slot is declared

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, slot, vue-slot

I have 3 components: App.vue (Entry point), slotWrapper.vue (Wrapping component), About.vue (Page Content).

Inside the 'App.vue' i have the router-view setup which is wrapped with 'slotWrapper.vue' component. The 'slotWrapper' component has a `<slot>` where the current route will be rendered.

My question: Inside the About.vue page (which will be rendered instead of the `<slot>`, of the slotWrapper.vue component) I have a computed value which I somehow need to pass back to 'slotWrapper.vue' component to use. How would I achieve such a thing.

I looked into `ScopedSlots` but I can't figure our how to use it where the content rendered is provided by a router.

Link to: [CodeSanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-routing-slots-fz2o6q?file=/App.vue)

App.Vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <slotWrapper>
      <router-view />
    </slotWrapper>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import slotWrapper from "./components/SlotWrapper.vue";
export default {
  name: "app",
  components: {
    slotWrapper,
  },
};
</script>
```

SlotWrapper.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="wrpperClass">
    <slot />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "SlotWrapper",
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.wrpperClass {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  color: black;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
</style>
```

About.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <slotWrapper>
      <router-view />
    </slotWrapper>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import slotWrapper from "./components/SlotWrapper.vue";
export default {
  name: "app",
  components: {
    slotWrapper,
  },
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  margin: 60px;
}

.link {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}

.router-link-active {
  color: green;
}
</style>
```

Router: index.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Router from "vue-router";
import About from "../components/About";

Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
  mode: "history",

  routes: [
    { path: "/", redirect: "about" },
    {
      path: "/about",
      component: About
      // props: (route) => ({ name: route.query.name })
    }
  ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who might face this issue. I figured that you can pass `props` to `<router-view>` and listen to `emits`. Since you can listen to `emits` I simply emit from the `about.vue` page and listen on the `app.vue`, and later using props I pass the variable down to `slotWrapper.vue`.

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <slotWrapper :propToPass="propToPass">
      <router-view @comp-data="receiveFunction" />
    </slotWrapper>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import slotWrapper from "./components/SlotWrapper.vue";
export default {
  name: "app",
  data() {
    return { propToPass: null };
  },
  components: {
    slotWrapper,
  },
  methods: {
    receiveFunction(data) {
      this.propToPass = data;
      console.log("From emit: ", data);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

About.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h3>About Page</h3>
    <p>
      I need this data:
      <span style="color: green">'ComputedData'</span> available inside
      'SlotWrapper'
    </p>
    <p>{{ ComputedData }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "About",
  data() {
    return {
      someVariable: "'someVariable'",
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    setTimeout(this.sendData, 2000);
  },
  computed: {
    ComputedData() {
      return (
        this.someVariable + " How do I become accessible inside slotWrapper?"
      );
    },
  },
  methods: {
    sendData() {
      this.$emit("comp-data", this.ComputedData);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```